# How to reduce cache misses on graph traversal algorithms like DFS and BFS?

Tags: multithreading, performance, algorithm, caching, memory-management

I would like to know how to modify the basic BFS and DFS algorithms so that when they are implemented either sequentially or in parallel incur less cache misses.

I read that **ordering of the vertices (or) nodes could help in reducing cache misses to an extent**, but I couldn't exactly understand how an ordering algorithm like RCM(Reverse Cuthill–McKee) would help in reducing cache misses on a basic Intel architecture (say a multicore with private L1, L2 and shared L3)?

Are there any other ideas to reduce cache misses apart from ordering vertices?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that reordering **can help** but it **is not guaranteed** to do that. Let's take the structure below as example, where on each row, you have the node's neighbors.

```
Node 1: 4, 5, 37, 12, 11, 2, 3
Node 2: 67, 11, 33, 45
Node 3:
......
Node N: 65, 56, 99, 44, 32, 1, 3
```

When you do DFS for example and you are at node 1. When you find node 37, you need to *jump at node 37*, but ***node 2 is probably closer in memory***, thus the higher chances of being cached. So **sorting the vertices reduces the jump step through memory thus reducing the cache misses**.

However, I think that the sorting can be done a bit smarter. For example, when you sort the vertices for node let's say 100, nodes 1, 2, 3 are far, so you may be interested in putting first, the neighboring nodes that are closer to node 100. So basically **sort the nodes according to the distance from the target node**.

These techniques might help for very large graphs but *depend heavily on the graph's topology*.

To propose a graph structure, I would do like this:

I would use 2 x 1D arrays:

- One to store all the neighbors of each node
- One to store for each node, the index in the first array where his neighbors start

**Example:**

```
Neighbors: 1 2 3 4 2 4 5 6 7 9 0
Neighbor Indexes: 0 2 5 7 9

The neighbors of Node 0 will start from Neighbors[Neighbor Indexes[0]] until Neighbors[Neighbor Indexes[1]].
The neighbors of Node 1 will start from Neighbors[Neighbor Indexes[1]] until Neighbors[Neighbor Indexes[2]].
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks @VAndrei for your reply. I can see how ordering may help. 
1. I have a doubt here. Suppose I used an array a[100], node0 will be in a[0 ], node1 in a[1], so on. When I need to get attributes of node50 I will go to a[50]. But now due to ordering, this is no longer the case. I need someway to figure out where in a[] is my node50. How would i do it (an example)? Doesn't it add an over head in searching the node!

2.Are there other ideas for optimization apart from ordering? Like what is the best data structure to use, how do I store the attributes of each node(struct), adjacency list, etc.

Comment: @Shyam I don't think you need to reorder the nodes but for each node, reorder the vertices according to the distance from the target node. See my updated post for a structure proposal.

Comment: "for each node, reorder the vertices according to the distance from the target node" - I am sorry. I don't really get you. Do you mean to reorder the adjacency list of each node based on the distance from the target node?

In the example, "Neighbors" are the adjacency list of each node? Can you please explain a little more on what "Neighbors" and "Neighbor Indexes" represent with respect to a given graph with nodes[] and edges[].

Comment: @Shyam. Yes, neighbors are adjacency list for each node. Neighbor Index[K] is the index in the neighbor array where the neighbor list of node K begins. When sorting, you need to sort the adjacency list for each node. So when you visit node 1000, you want to firstly visit neighbor nodes 999, 998 because in the structure that keeps the graph they are closer, thus cached.

Comment: makes sense. Instead of having two 1D arrays: one for the adjacency list of all nodes, another pointing to the start of adjacency list of each node, Can I have a array of arraylist or an vector where each element stores the list of adjacent vertices in a sorted order. Ex. Adj[0]={8,10,17} stores a list of Node0 neighbours in a sorted order. Isn't the same what your trying to explain as well in a different approach. Which is the better one. Why?

Comment: If you use an array of arraylist (basically an array of pointers), your structure would be fragmented in the memory so that will make caching less efficient. I recommend my solution because this way the graph structure is a contigous block in memory and caching will be much more effective,